# Make List of Items C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a very big issuse here. I'm trying to make a list off all cars and push them to View, but it doesn't work as I assume. Any idea how can I do that ?? I would be very thankfull

Here is my Car Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Automarket.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Net;

namespace Automarket.Controllers
{
    public class CarController : Controller
    {
        OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext();
        private object Viewbag;
        private readonly object ds;

        // GET: Automarket
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            List<Marke> marke = db.Marke.ToList();
            List<Modeli> modeli = db.Modeli.ToList();
            JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string deps = oSerializer.Serialize(modeli);
            ViewData["deps"] = deps;
            ViewData["marke"] = marke;
            ViewData["modeli"] = modeli;
            return View(db.car.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Cars/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Car car = db.car.Find(id);
            if (car == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(car);
        }

        // GET: Cars/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CarID,Make,Model,Price,Registration,Mileage,FuealType,Country,ZipCode,Picture")] Car car)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.car.Add(car);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(car);
        }

        // GET: Cars/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Car car = db.car.Find(id);
            if (car == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(car);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CarID,Make,Model,Price,Registration,Mileage,FuealType,Country,ZipCode,Picture")] Car car)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(car).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(car);
        }

        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Car car = db.car.Find(id);
            if (car == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(car);
        }

        // POST: Cars/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Car car = db.car.Find(id);
            db.car.Remove(car);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


    }
}
```

Here is my Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Automarket.Models
{
    public class Car
    {

        public int CarID { get; set; }      
        public string Make { get; set; }      
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public int Registration { get; set; }
        public double Mileage { get; set; }
        public string FuealType { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public int ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string pathToImage  { get; set; }



    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you show your view code?

Comment: I don't have. Just deleted View, because doesn't work

Comment: Error message? In the view you put `@model List<type_car>`?

Comment: I just add method for display the List of Cars in Controller:

public ActionResult DisplayCars()
        {
            List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
            Car car = new Car();
            db.car.Add(car);
            return View();
        }
And In View I get error message here:

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_kkbg42sx.dll but was not handled in user code


@foreach (var item in Model) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a list of objects in your view, bascally, you need:

In Controller, send a list of objects to View using `View(<data>)` method:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext();
    return View(db.car.ToList());
}
```

In View, receive the list of objects in Model variable:

```
@model List<Car>

<html>
...
<body>
    @foreach(var item in Model) {
        <p>@item.Property</p>
    }
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you man so much :)

Comment: ;-) Please, if this is useful, accept this answer as resolve your question/problem.